# Without any decorator or any wrapper method or inheriting how to call the common method when specific a method call on multiple methods in python?

Tags: python

Suppose you have multiple methods in python and a common method. When we call any of these methods that include multiple methods then the common method will automatically call. Here is the bellow implementation using a decorator. How to implement this problem without any decorator or wrap method or inheriting it?

```
from aspectlib import Aspect

def common_method():
  print("Common method called")

@Aspect
def aspect_for_methods(*args, **kwargs):
   common_method()  # Executed before the method call
   yield
   common_method()  # Executed after the method call

@aspect_for_methods
def method1():
  print("Method 1 called")

@aspect_for_methods
def method2():
  print("Method 2 called")

# Example usage:
method1()
method2()
```

I am not able to solve this problem. So please provide the implementation of this problem without using any decorator or inheriting this common method or without using a wrapper function using Python.

Comment: Please show your code. What have you tried and what doesn’t work?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can create function which executes original function and common function and you can assign it to original function - so you can simulate decorator without using decorator. But this need more work then normal decorator.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a decorator?

Comment: @ndc85430 I just wonder if is it possible to implement this problem without using the wrapper method or without using decorators or without inheriting it.

Comment: @furas I just wonder if is it possible to implement this problem without using the wrapper method or without using decorators or without inheriting it.

Comment: @AnikMahmud based on your profile, is this a competitive programming situation where you are required not to use a decorator or wrapper method? A decorator is the natural and pythonic way to do it.

Comment: @slothrop besides my profile, please you tell me is it implement or not?

Comment: @AnikMahmud your comment reads like "I am not going to answer your question. Please answer mine". Have a good day.

Comment: The decorator pattern (of which Python's decorators are an example) is quite a well-known solution for this type of thing. The template pattern might also be relevant, but you're also saying you don't want to use inheritance, not that you have any classes in your example. I'm not really understanding your objection to standard approaches.

Comment: I think you can't do this without wrapper. Eventually it would need to make mess with AST (Abstract Syntax Trees) - so it is not worth the trouble. Besides even with `AST` it may looks like wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
def common_method():
    print("Common method called!")

def wrap(method):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        common_method()
        method(*args, **kwargs)
        common_method()
    return wrapped

def method_1():
    print("Method 1 called!")

# it can receive args
def method_2(x, y):
    print(f"Method called with {x} & {y}!")

method_1_wrapped = wrap(method_1)
method_1_wrapped()

# it can even override the original function name
method_2 = wrap(method_2)
method_2(3.14, y=42)
```

You can try it [here](https://www.online-python.com/nBFDsUvtko).

Comment: I think not using the wrap(method)